# Finding Lyapunov function. $x'=Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=Ax$ and

$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&&-2&&0\\2&&1&&0\\0&&0&&-3\end{pmatrix}$

> I want to prove that $x=0$ is stable. There is a hint: Find a Lyapunov function in the form of $V(x)=x^TPx$. Determine $P \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}$.

For symmetric $P$ we have $\nabla x^TPx=2Px$, so I started with symmetric $P$.

$P=\begin{pmatrix}a&&b&&c\\b&&d&&e\\c&&e&&f\end{pmatrix}$

$\frac{dV}{dt}(x(t))=\nabla V(x(t))(Ax)=2(Px)(Ax)\stackrel{!}<0$

> I think something is wrong with the dimensions here. Do I need $2(Px)^T$?

$2Px=2\begin{pmatrix}ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\\bx_1+dx_2+ex_3\\cx_2+ex_2+fx_3\end{pmatrix}$

$2(Px)^{T(?)}(Ax)=2(-a+2b)x_1^2+2\big((-2a-2b+2d)x_2-4x_3(c-e/2)\big)x_1+2(-2b-d)x_2^2-4x_3(c+2e)x_2-6fx_3$

Then I set up equations such that mixed terms are zero and the factors in front of $x_1^2$, $x_2^2$ and $x_3^2$ are equal to $-1$.

i.e. $2(-a+2b)=-1,\ (-2a-2b+2d)=0,\ (c-e/2)=0,\ 2(-2b-d)=-1,\ (c+2e)=0,\ (-6f)=-1$

Which gives

$P=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&&0&&0\\0&&1/2&&0\\0&&0&&1/6\end{pmatrix}$

So we indeed have

$V(0)=0$

$V(x)>0$ for $x \neq 0$ because $P$ is positive definite

$\frac{dV}{dt}(x(t))=-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)<0$ for $x\neq 0$

First of all I don't know if the above is correct.

> there a better way to find $V(x)$ and $P$?
>
> How could I directly show that $x=0$ is stable?

Comment: For linear tiem-invariant systems (like the one in your question), stability is not related to the equilibrium points, but rather related to the system itself. If A has all the eigenvalues with negative real part, then the system is stable. That is all the initial conditions converge to zero.

Comment: I think your solution is correct.